# Find the sum of the volumes

Tags: spheres

Let $d$ be the distance between the centers of two spheres which are in contact with each other.

Let $A$ be the sum of the surface areas of the two spheres.

*Find the sum of the volumes of the two spheres(in terms of $d$ and $A$).*

Comment: What is your first idea? Can You first express $A$? This is pretty standard, don't you think so?

Comment: I have removed the tag "abstract-algebra", as this problem does not fall under that subject area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$R+r=d$$
$$4π(R^2+r^2)=A$$
$$R^2+r^2=\frac{A}{4π}$$
$$(R+r)^2=\frac{A}{4π}+2Rr$$
$$\frac{d^2-\frac{A}{4π}}{2}=Rr$$
Sum of volumes,
$$\frac{4π}{3}(R^3+r^3)=\frac{4π}{3}(R^2+r^2-Rr)(R+r)$$
$$ =\frac{4π}{3}(A-\frac{d^2-\frac{A}{4π}}{2})(d)$$
**$$    =\frac{8πAd-4πd^3+Ad}{6}$$**

Answer (score 0):

Let their radii be $r$ and $R$. Then $A=4\pi(r^2+R^2)$ and $d=r+R$. The sum of volumes is $\dfrac{4}{3}\pi(r^3+R^3)$.

$$r^3+R^3=(r+R)(r^2-rR+R^2)=d\left(\dfrac{A}{4\pi}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(d^2-\dfrac{A}{4\pi}\right)\right)$$
where we use that $d^2-\dfrac{A}{4\pi}=2rR$.